Model indexing on Choice field in django
i have a model which has a status field of choice field which are pending,approved,cancel,rejected. And i index the field status in my model and the makemigrations but the index only works for other values but not approved value. if i filter by other status like, pending,cancel it will shows that it get it from the index but if i filter by approved it won't work and it will load slowly. Though the dataset of the model is much which is around 7million.
I get the details from a django debug tools
this will show if i filter by other values
if i filter by other values
if i filter by approved value
this is my view which i use to test the filter
def testing(request): context['response'] = Task_Submitted.objects.filter(status='approved') return render(request, 'testing.html', context)
my model
    Tasks_submitedstatus = [
    ('pending','PENDING'),
    ('rejected','REJECTED'),
    ('approved','APPROVED'),
    ('cancel','CANCEL')
]
class Task_Submitted(models.Model):
status = models.CharField(choices=Tasks_submitedstatus, help_text='Status', null=True, max_length=8, db_index=True)

is there any way to fixed this so approved too will be in index so if i filter by approved value too it will load faster

Please don't use .values() when passing objects to the template: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Can you explain how you are filtering by approved?

i use normal filter Task_Submitted.objects.filter(status='approved')

i make a mistake in adding the values. i don't add the values when filtering by the status

I would advise not to write approved or cancelled to the database. But work with a short string. This will not only save disc space, but will also make it easier to filter on that column due to hashing and small indexes.
We can thus work with:

class Task(models.Model):
    STATUSSES = [
       ('p', 'pending'),
       ('a', 'approved'),
       ('c', 'cancelled'),
       ('r', 'rejected'),
    ]
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, db_index=True, choices=STATUSSES)
    # …
In the view, we pass Task objects, not .values():
def testing(request):
    return render(
        request, 'testing.html', {'response': Task.objects.filter(status='a')}
    )
and we can render in the template with:
{% for task in response %}
    {{ task.get_status_display }}
{% endfor %}
This will then render "approved", not "a".

please check the updated question. i make a mistake by adding the values when posting the quesstion

@ShittuAbdulrasheedAyomide: it doesn't change anything w.r.t. the solution.

i added the change but still slow in approved

but currently the application is using db.t3.medium database in aws could that be what makes it slow? and also what size of database can run that type of dataset, maybe it gets slow because of the database size
